# Default open UCI form for Dynamics 365 from Advanced Find

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-uci

Is there anyway to default open the record in UCI form from the results in Advanced Find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain how this UCI paradigm shift is happening. We are in transition phase from `(1) classic web UI` to `(2) hybrid classic and UCI` to `(3) UCI only in Oct 2020`. [Read more](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/moving-forward-with-your-transition-to-unified-interface/)

I believe you are in second stage, and UCI is not enforced yet. So you may have users using classic web and UCI app as well. But some OOB functionalities like Advanced find is still in transition. During this hybrid stage, you are facing issues like such I guess.

All the navigation concepts are happening using the url querystring parameters. You can inspect the url to check the pattern like below.

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?pagetype=advancedfind

https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?appid=017ca8fb-fbc9-47de-8af8-59ac190ae350&pagetype=AdvancedFind

https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?appid=017ca8fb-fbc9-47de-8af8-59ac190ae350&forceUCI=1&pagetype=AdvancedFind
```

That being said, if you don't have one of the last two type from the above patterns, then its highly unlikely opening the record from Advanced find results will open the UCI form.

Comment: Will the UCI only in Oct 2020 also applied to On-Premise? And which version will it be? Thanks.

Comment: @AnthonySteven the comment in this blog post says “2020 cut off is only for online customers and on premise customers will get support for classic web client” -  https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/dynamics365/it/2019/09/10/announcing-the-timeline-to-move-to-unified-interface/